# Extract all Components (button, Label etc) name and their length from another Delphi project

Tags: delphi

Is there any way from which I can extract all component names and their length of Delphi project file or I can do it one by one by iterate all forms in the project. And I want to store result in any file say .txt, word, pdf etc.

Comment: Delphi project files don't usually contain component names. That's not what you mean is it? You mean the components defined in your .dfm files I guess? So surely you can write a simple script to pick those out. Do you know any scripting languages?

Comment: you can use something like this - http://www.felix-colibri.com/papers/colibri_utilities/dfm_parser/dfm_parser.html

Comment: (but note that Felix' parser chokes on the [n] numbers in the .DFM: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916294/strange-numbers-in-delphi-dfm-files-origin-and-necessity)

Comment: What do you mean by _and their length_?

Comment: @NGLN I **guess** he is talking about the *width* :o)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i know javascript, ruby, python.

Comment: @NGLN by length  i mean like if it is a label what is it length of string it can hold without clipping or wrapping similar for button as well

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. What's stopping you writing the code?